# Can I scale down the widgets in DevExtreme web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

In a DevExtreme web application all the editor widgets are relatively too big (e.g. dxCheckbox).

Can I scale down the widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now all you can do is just use css to scale down widget size.

This fiddle shows how to do it for checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/uhamqm9k/

Use following styles

```
.dx-widget {
    font-size: 12px;    
}

.dx-checkbox-icon {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
```

But I heard about plans on compact theme for webapps.

Comment: Ok, I hope that compact theme is coming soon...Thanks!

Comment: What you could also try is following css `.dx-widget { transform: scale(.8); }`. The scale value here depends on you case.

Comment: I have to make this work on IE9, so I find out -ms- prefix is needed: .dx-widget { -ms-transform: scale(.8); }. It works for a checkbox. Later I will test it with a more complex ui... Thanks for help!